# Getting HTTP 404 Error when using a bootstrap / css template in Flask

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I just started learning Flask yesterday, and tried to make a simple single page webpage. I copied a Bootstrap template I found online, but when I run my main python program I keep getting the following errors:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [26/May/2019 23:13:15] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

127.0.0.1 - - [26/May/2019 22:13:15] "GET /vendor/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -

127.0.0.1 - - [26/May/2019 22:13:15] "GET /vendor/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -

127.0.0.1 - - [26/May/2019 22:13:15] "GET /vendor/full-width-pics.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -

127.0.0.1 - - [26/May/2019 22:13:15] "GET /vendor/bootstrap.bundle.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

This is my root directory:

```
-FortniteStatBot.py

-Templates
| 
|----index.html
|
|----vendor
|
|---- All the other static files
```

I have looked at other posts on stack overflow and tried everything people suggested, but it doesn't fix the problem. Some things I have tried are adding static url paths / folders. Also saw someone recommend that I remove trailing '/' in the directory path, but that didn't fix it either.

---

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path= '', static_folder= '/Templates/vendor')

app._static_folder = 'Templates/vendor'
```

I tried something like this in my html file, and it didn't work either:

```
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='/vendor/bootstrap.min.css/') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

---

I keep getting the same error despite trying multiple different things, so I'm wondering if anyone knows how to fix this error?

I am using this return value in the only function inside the .py file:

```
return render_template('index.html', stats = accountInfo, accountName = playerName)
```

Comment: `app = Flask(__name__, static_folder= 'Templates/vendor')` and `<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: and see this docs http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/static/

Comment: I tried that just now, and I still get the 404 errors

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `templates_folder` in combination with `static_folder`. From the docs:

> `static_folder` – the folder with static files that should be served at
>
> `template_folder` – the folder that contains the templates that should be used by the application. Defaults to 'templates' folder in the root path of the application.

Comment: So I should make a separate folder for the index.html?

Comment: By default, Flask is looking for `static` and `templates` folders for those respective files. If you put your `index.html` into `/templates`, and the static files (vendor, etc) into `/static`, you remove the need to specify these in the app creation.

Comment: I noticed that when I moved all the files into static, and separated the index.html, there was a slight error with the picture showing a broken thumbnail. 

[link](https://imgur.com/a/NBsXEH6)
This is the code which is responsible for that image.

`<header class="py-5 bg-image-full" style="background-image: url('https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp2366069.jpg');">
    <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="https://i.imgur.com/npdrX8w.png" alt="">
  </header>`

Comment: @fadedxenos, the code looks okay and the image loads when you go to the url directly, so there may be something else causing it. Have a look in the console to see if there's any errors etc to help find the issue.

Comment: Yeah I tried using Google Chrome and it ended up working. I was testing this on Microsoft Edge and I guess something wasn't compatible :/

Thanks for all the help man! You saved me a lot of time